# width:100% when you click on an item

Tags: html, css

what should I do so that when you click an element from `<li>` the width of hover background becomes 100% of page width?
I already tried the line 100% on .navbar a:hover

```
.navbar {
display: flex;
list-style-type: none;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
height: 150px;
margin: 0%;
background-image: linear-gradient(grey, black);
}

.navbar a {
text-decoration: none;
font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
color: blanchedalmond;
}

.navbar a:hover {
color: gray;
background-color: goldenrod;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify any width.

The width from **navbar:hover**, will be inheritance from standard **navbar**, unless you overwrite the attribute.

I also recommend you this plugin - https://css2sass.herokuapp.com/

It's works great (changing css to scss || sass)

```
 .navbar {
      display: flex;
      list-style-type: none;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      height: 150px;
      margin: 0%;
      background-image: linear-gradient(grey, black);

      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
        color: blanchedalmond;

        &:hover {
          color: gray;
          background-color: goldenrod;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: i tried with width 100% on .navbar and width 100% on hover, don't work. also when i try width 100% on .navbar there appear a scrollbar downside

Comment: What effect You wan't to accomplish?

Comment: When i click an element from navbar like 'home' the background color 'goldenrod' to look like a line with 100% width, not just a square around the word